# Does the msgraph-sdk-javascript library support SSO-OBO?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently looking for a good JS library to use for my addin. And I came across this project : [MSGRAPH-SDK-JAVASCRIPT](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/wiki)

I tried to read through their project details but could not find out definitively if they support the SSO-OBO flow for addins.

Has anybody used the said library successfully for an SSO-OBO flow?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single sign on and MS Graph SDK are different things. You can use SSO to deal with Graph API from Outlook web add-ins. See [Using Single Sign-On (SSO) with Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/office-add-ins-sso/) for more information.

Also you may find the following posts helpful:

- [Authorize to Microsoft Graph with SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph)
- [Authenticate a user with a single-sign-on token in an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authenticate-a-user-with-an-sso-token)

Comment: Hello Eugene. Thank you for your responses. I now understand :

(1) The Microsoft Graph JavaScript client library is a lightweight wrapper around the Microsoft Graph API that can be used server-side and in the browser.

(2) Single sign on and MS Graph SDK are different things. You can use SSO to deal with Graph API from Outlook web add-ins. 

Since SSO is for Outlook web add-ins which is not server-side nor in the browser.